# Group fields in Django's admin forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm pretty new to Django and experimenting with it.

I've read a quite amount of docs about the framework but I could not find information on how to **"group" fields in admin forms**.

What I mean by grouping is having an *arbitrary number of fields grouped under an arbitrary subsection* (the way the subsection is represented graphically is not important).

Is it possible to "natively" do that (by natively, I mean without overriding any Admin Form)?

Comment: I think you might be looking for [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets).

Comment: @Alasdair: exactly what I was looking for... could not find it because I kept searching with the "group" keyword. You can add it as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can do this with fieldsets.

For example:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
           'fields': ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
        }),
        ('Advanced options', {
            'fields': ('field4', 'field5'),
        }),
    )
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) for more information.

Comment: Gah I still love Django :) Makes my life so much easier...